# find a set of path within a string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a string which may get bigger over time. I need to find out the artifacts path in the string. Is there a way to get all the artifacts path as highlighted using regex? I have block quoted them. what would be the reggae for such a scenario?

```
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py:57: PowmInsecureWarning: Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.
  _warn("Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.", PowmInsecureWarning)
[SSH] exit-status: 0
For pattern: *.py 10 artifacts were found
For pattern: *.md 1 artifacts were found
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/elb_ec2Connector.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/elb_ec2Connector_Tony.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/naren_weekend_stop.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/naren_4th_box.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/startontags.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/nitish.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/krishna.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/naren_weekend.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/get-pip.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/startup_script.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test2/test3/test4/test5/test6/README.m

Deploying build info to: artifactory/artifactory/api/build
Collecting metadata...
Metadata collection done.
```

The whole thing above is string, I need to figure out a way to get just  the following part from this:

```
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/elb_ec2Connector.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/elb_ec2Connector_Tony.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/naren_weekend_stop.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/naren_4th_box.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/startontags.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/nitish.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/krishna.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/naren_weekend.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/get-pip.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test4/test5/startup_script.py
Deploying artifact: artifactory/artifactory/yum-local/test/test2/test3/test4/test5/test6/README.m
```

Please keep in mind the path may keep changing the other strings though the initial words Deployment artifacts will remain the same and all paths will appear together in the logs...

Comment: What's the string? That whole thing? What's the path you're trying to grab? We need concrete example input and output

Comment: @AdamSmith - check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty easy.

```
artifact_paths = re.findall(r"^Deploying artifact: .*$", full_string, re.M)
```

Comment: Sorry, first time using regex . I tried this it returned empty list...

Comment: @Scooby whoops, my fault, forgot for multi-line strings you have to use `re.M` to get that `^` `$` behavior. Edited.